# Search array to disply list in html

Tags: javascript, html, list

I have an array containing a number of items (below), my aim is to be able to use a search bar to search for an item or items matching a keyword for it and then generate a list of matching products in html to display them

```
  const catalog = {
        "Ipad": {
          "name": "Ipad",
          "key": "ipad",
          "keywords": ["tablet", "apple"],
          "price": 800
        },
        "Iphone": {
          "name": "Iphone",
                "key": "iphone",
          "keywords": ["apple", "phone"],
          "price": 1200
        },
        "GalaxyTablet": {
          "name": "GalaxyTablet",
          "key": "galaxytablet",
          "keywords": ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
          "price": 800
        },
        "GalaxyPhone": {
          "name": "GalaxyPhone",
          "key": "galaxyphone",
          "keywords": ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
          "price": 1000
        },
        "HTCPhone": {
          "name": "HTCPhone",
          "key": "htcphone",
          "keywords": ["htc", "phone"],
          "price": 650
        },
        "SonyPhone": {
          "name": "SonyPhone",
          "key": "sonyphone",
          "keywords": ["sony", "phone"],
          "price": 850
        },
        "WindowsPhone": {
          "name": "WindowsPhone",
          "key": "windowsphone",
          "keywords": ["phone", "windows"],
          "price": 800
        },

      };
```

Comment: This is not an array but object. Also what will be the input in searchbar?

Comment: Well i'd be searching by using a keyword term to try and match against that contained in the list of objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate each object from your data and filtered it out by search keyword as shown in below code.

```js
const catalog = {
  "Ipad": {
    "name": "Ipad",
    "key": "ipad",
    "keywords": ["tablet", "apple"],
    "price": 800
  },
  "Iphone": {
    "name": "Iphone",
    "key": "iphone",
    "keywords": ["apple", "phone"],
    "price": 1200
  },
  "GalaxyTablet": {
    "name": "GalaxyTablet",
    "key": "galaxytablet",
    "keywords": ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    "price": 800
  },
  "GalaxyPhone": {
    "name": "GalaxyPhone",
    "key": "galaxyphone",
    "keywords": ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    "price": 1000
  },
  "HTCPhone": {
    "name": "HTCPhone",
    "key": "htcphone",
    "keywords": ["htc", "phone"],
    "price": 650
  },
  "SonyPhone": {
    "name": "SonyPhone",
    "key": "sonyphone",
    "keywords": ["sony", "phone"],
    "price": 850
  },
  "WindowsPhone": {
    "name": "WindowsPhone",
    "key": "windowsphone",
    "keywords": ["phone", "windows"],
    "price": 800
  },

};

const searchKeyword = 'apple';
const finalResult = []
for (const items in catalog) {
  const obj = catalog[items];
  if (obj.keywords.indexOf(searchKeyword) != -1) {
    finalResult.push(obj);
  }
}

console.log(finalResult);
```